# Visul Studio 2017 error "Failed tp complile the project in memory" Please use Language Version 7.3 or greater

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I have a project that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.Net Core 2.2 framework. This project started at ASP.NET Core 2.1 and was upgraded to 2.2.

This project contains code that is utilizing some of the latest features in C# compiler 7.3 which is required for my project to compile. To force my project to use C# compiler 7.3, I added the following to my `.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that changing `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` to `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` will not work for some reason the project will fail to compile. It's like Visual Studio thinks 7.3 is not the latest or is not aware of its existence.

The above code makes the project compile using the latest C# compiler 7.3. However, I am now trying to scaffold Identity items using the following steps

1. From **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the project > **Add** > **New Scaffolded Item**.
2. From the left pane of the **Add Scaffold** dialog, select **Identity** > **ADD**.
3. In the **ADD Identity** dialog, choose files you wish to override.

   1. Select layout if necessary
   2. Select or create **Data context class**.
4. Hit **ADD**.

But that is giving me the following error "Failed to compile the project in memory"

It seems as Visual Studio 2017 is trying to compile the project in the memory during the scaffolding process using C# compiler 7.0 instead of C# compiler 7.3 which is why I am getting this error. Keep in mind that my project will not compile unless C# compiler 7.3+ is used.
[image]

How can I force Visual Studio 2017 to use C# compiler 7.3 everywhere in my project and in the memory?

Comment: I haven't done anything with .NET Core 2.2 yet, but I believe you need Update 9 to handle it properly.  Did you upgrade VS to the latest update?

Comment: I updated Visial Studio yes. My current version is 15.9.4.

Comment: @Has your problem been solved right now?

Comment: @TanvirArjel no.

Comment: Have you tried <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

Comment: Yes I have. That will make the project use c# compiler 7.0. It’s like the default compiler is 7.0 and is also marked as the latest

Comment: if you run `dotnet --version`, what do you get?

Comment: @zaitsman The command `dotnet --version` returns 2.2.101

Comment: Ok, that's (almost) current; and what about VS version?

Comment: Vs version 15.9.4

Comment: Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/834).Have you tried your steps with a complete new core 2.2 MVC project with Identity? I try and it works.

Comment: I upgraded a project from 2.1 to 2.2. I don't want to have to start a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but the error is clear. You're using **enum generic constraints** in two clases.

> EnumMenuViewModel, line 7, column 105.
>
> EnumOptionalMenuViewModel, line 6.

The scaffolding compiles the project using C# 7.0, and this feature is not available.

You can disable these constraints, run the scaffolding, then enable it again.

I hope it helps someone.